# not able to clone repo via ssh (gitea)

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gitea

I've tried to deploy the 'gitea' on my virtual machine.

gitea version is:

```
$ ./gitea -v
Gitea version 1.3.2 built with: bindata, sqlite
```

os:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

gitea config:

```
SSH_DOMAIN       = <ip address>
DOMAIN           = <ip address>
HTTP_PORT        = 3000
ROOT_URL         = https://<ip address>/
DISABLE_SSH      = false
SSH_PORT         = 2222
LFS_START_SERVER = true
LFS_CONTENT_PATH = /home/git/data/lfs
LFS_JWT_SECRET   = Sxp3S45YtJMKPzVpcQZ9OvltVkTRGzdUVd4jU95irsE
OFFLINE_MODE     = false
PROTOCOL         = https
CERT_FILE        = /home/git/cert.pem
KEY_FILE         = /home/git/key.pem
SSH_ROOT_PATH    = /home/git/.ssh
START_SSH_SERVER = true
SSH_LISTER_PORT  = 22
```

everything works fine except ssh. I mean I am able to work with repo via https,
but I have no luck in using ssh
the error is displaying:

```
$ ssh -T git@<ip address> 
Hi there, You've successfully authenticated, but Gitea does not provide shell access.
If this is unexpected, please log in with password and setup Gitea under another user.
```

Can someone assist me in fixing that matter?

Comment: when I try to clone the repo
the 'git clone' command is hunging

$ git clone ssh://git@<ip address>/test-user/test-repo-1.git
Cloning into 'test-repo-1'...
^C

Answer (score 1):

this issue can be fixed by disabling LFS server

```
root@ACA80006:/home/test# grep -i lfs_start_server /home/git/custom/conf/app.ini
LFS_START_SERVER = false
```

Comment: I can confirm that this fix works! Thanks for posting!